# Does $A\times X \cong B\times X$ implies $A\cong B$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A, B, X$ be any topological spaces. Let
$$
A\times X\cong B\times X
$$
Thus, there exist continuous maps
$$A\times X\ \xrightarrow{f}  B\times X  \text{ and }  B\times X\ \xrightarrow{g}  A\times X $$
s.t.
$f\circ g = 1_{B\times X}$ and $g\circ f = 1_{A\times X}$

Let $\iota_A: A\times X\to A$ such that $\iota_A(a,x) = a$ for all $(a,x)\in A\times X$.

Let $\iota_B: B\times X\to B$ be defined similarly.

Then, since continuity of maps is invariant under composition
$$
f\circ g = 1_{B\times X} \implies \iota_B\circ(f\circ g) = \iota_B\circ (1_{B\times X})
$$
That is,
$$
\iota_B\circ(f\circ g) = 1_{B}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\iota_A\circ(g\circ f) = 1_{A}
$$
But, this is where I get stuck. I wish I could use $\iota_B \circ f$ and $\iota_A\circ g$ as continuous inverses--but this clearly doesn't work, as codomains and domains don't necessarily align. Maybe I could possibly use that $X\cong (X\times \{0\}$ to force the codomains and domains to match up for composition.

But, honestly, I'm not even sure I'm fully convinced that what I'm trying to prove is even true. I think the converse may be true, though. That $A\cong B\implies A\times X \cong B\times X$. I assume I could probably use that if $f,g$ are continuous inverses for $A\cong B$, then $(f\times 1_x)$ and $(g\times 1_x)$ are likely also continuous inverses for $A\times X \cong B\times X$.

Comment: One immediate counterexample is $X=\varnothing$. A less trivial one is $A=\mathbb{R}$, $B=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $X=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You could replace $\ math i\ $ (it associates with inclusion and injection) with \$\ p\ $ or $\ \pi\ $ (it associates with projections).

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

There are many counterexamples available, take $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and see if you can find non-homeomorphic  $A$, $B$ satisfying  $A\times X \simeq B\times X$.

$\bf{Added:}$ $A=[0,1)$, $B=[0,1]$, $X=[0,1)$ is a nice example.

Comment: What does $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ mean?

Comment: It's sequences of $0$ or $1$, with product topology. It's homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider discrete spaces $A,B,X$ with $|X|\ge\aleph_0$ and $0\lt|A|\lt|B|\le|X|$.